# $f$ analytic in neighborhood of closure of $\mathbb{D}$. If $f$ is real on boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, maximum-principle

Question: Let $f$ be an analytic function in a neighborhood of the closure of $\mathbb{D}$.  Show that if $f$ is real on all the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$, then $f$ must be constant.

Thoughts: I feel like this should be done using maximum modulus principle, but I am not quite sure how to do it.   Since $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the closure of $\mathbb{D}$, maybe we can use some partial derivative stuff since C-R equations must be satisfied and the fourt partial derivatives are continuous... Any thoughts or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MMP is the right approach. Let $g(z)=e^{if(z)}$. Note that $|g(z)|=1$ for all $z$ on the boundary. Use MMP for $g$ and $\frac 1 g$ to show that $|g|$ is a  constant. This implies that $g$ is itself a constant. Now  conclude that $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Alternately, use $g = \operatorname{Im} f$.  So $g$ is a harmonic function, zero on the boundary.  The maximum principle for harmonic functions shows $g = 0$ on all of $\mathbb D$.  By the open mapping theorem, $f$ is constant on $\mathbb D$.