# Analytic $f$ is real on $\partial U$ implies $f$ being constant with $U = \{|z| < 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function in a neighborhood of $\bar{U}$ where $U = \{|z| < 1\}$. Show that if $f$ is real on $\partial U$, then $f$ must be constant.
$$$$
My first aim is since a circle cancelled a dot is holomorphic to $x$-axis, and $f(x)=x$ satisfies $f$ is real on $x$-axis, we need to use some properties that a circle have but an $x$-axis doesn't have. I think both the maximum principle and the open mapping theorem can be a choice, but I don't know how to properly use them in this problem. Does anyone has any ideas about this? Or we shouldn't use the above two theorems here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482976/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|e^{\pm if(z)}|=1$ for $|z|=1$. Apply Maximum Modulus Principle to $e^{if}$ and $e^{-if}$ to conclude that $|e^{if}|=1$ for $|z| \leq 1$. Can you now prove that $e^{if}$ must be a constant and hence $f$ itself is a constant?

Comment: Yes, $e^{if}$ is constant due to open mapping theorem, so how did you come up with the idea of considering $e^{if}$?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc True. I thought MMP for harmonic functions is less known than MMP for analytic functions.

Comment: Oh, we can use poisson formula to obtain that $Im(f)=0$ in unit disk

Comment: You gave the same answer to an identical question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4136977/42969 – found quickly with a search for “real on boundary” in the [complex-analysis] tag.